# Puxar Atributo nomeServico de outra classe na view Agenda usando a chave estrangeira IDServico com Razor Asp.Net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, razor-pages

Tenho uma view **Index** que lista os agendamentos.

Nessa lista aparece os atributos da agenda incluindo uma chave estrangeira `IDServico`, no entanto, a lista aparece apenas o índice do `IDServico` e preciso que apareça o **Nome do Serviço**.

O código que apresenta o índice está dessa forma:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AutorizacaoAgenda)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hora)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Disponibilidade)
        </td>
        @*Aqui é o código para mostrar o IDServico*@
        <td>
            **@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDServico)**
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Minha `Controller` está assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ProjetoBarber.Models;

namespace ProjetoBarber.Controllers
{
    public class AgendaController : Controller
    {
        private BarbeariaDB db = new BarbeariaDB();

        // GET: Agenda
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var agendas = db.Agendas.Include(t => t.Servico);
            ViewBag.IDServico = new SelectList(db.Servicos, "ID", "Nome");
            return View(agendas);


        }

        // GET: Agenda/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Agenda agenda = db.Agendas.Find(id);
            if (agenda == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(agenda);
        }

        // GET: Agenda/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.IDServico = new SelectList(db.Servicos, "ID", "Nome");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Agenda/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Data,Hora,IDServico,IDUsuario")] Agenda agenda)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Agendas.Add(agenda);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.IDServico = new SelectList(db.Servicos, "ID", "Nome",agenda.IDServico);
            return View(agenda);
        }

        // GET: Agenda/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Agenda agenda = db.Agendas.Find(id);
            if (agenda == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(agenda);
        }

        // POST: Agenda/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Data,Hora,IDServico,IDUsuario")] Agenda agenda)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(agenda).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(agenda);
        }

        // GET: Agenda/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Agenda agenda = db.Agendas.Find(id);
            if (agenda == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(agenda);
        }

        // POST: Agenda/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Agenda agenda = db.Agendas.Find(id);
            db.Agendas.Remove(agenda);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pessoal, Tentei dessa forma mas sem sucesso: 
<td>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Servico.Nome)           
</td>                                                                                            
A controller está da seguinte forma: 
// GET: Agenda
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var agendas = db.Agendas.Include(t => t.Servico);
            ViewBag.IDServico = new SelectList(db.Servicos, "ID", "Nome");

            return View(db.Agendas.ToList());
        }
Por que não lista o serviço no lugar do indice?

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e inclusa sua action e suas model Agendas e Servico

Answer (score 0):

Você selecionou a lista com os serviços porém não retornou ela, mude para o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
    var agendas = db.Agendas.Include(t => t.Servico); 
    ViewBag.IDServico = new SelectList(db.Servicos, "ID", "Nome"); 
    return View(agendas); 
}
```

Você diz:

> Nessa lista aparece os **atributos**

Aconselho que leia essa pergunta/resposta: [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269089/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-atributo-e-campo-nas-classes) para entender mais sobre o que é atributo.

Comment: na View coloquei dessa forma: 

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDServico)

Porém dessa forma aparece o valor do campo ID.
Se coloco dessa forma:

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Servico.Nome)

Não aparece nada.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: @PedroTomaz,  olha na minha resposta, você precisa deixar sua ActionResult conforme informei, você chega a dar o Include em serviço, mas não está retornando o objeto correto para a View

Comment: Alterei a Action conforme sua alteração, porém não deu certo. Por isso passei o código da View para verificar se estava certo. Mas ainda não consegui corrigir o problema.

Comment: @PedroTomaz, por favor, edite a pergunta adicionando como está seu controller